# Copy URL parameters and inject them in another URL

Tags: javascript

)
I've to copy the parameters of the current page URL and inject them in a new URL to place in the href of a button, on the same current page. The page is made by WordPress + Divi.

So I put a custom ID for the button that fires a script. My script is quite complicated and I suppose it could be simplified but it works...until I try to inject the new URL in the href button.

So my goal is to have "https://website.com/new-url/?f=John&l=Doe& ..."
from "https://website.com/current-url/?f=John&l=Doe& ..."
and place the new URL in the href button that is on the current-url

If someone could help me, I thank him in advance!

Heres is my code :

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url = window.location.href) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
var f_value = getParameterByName('f');
var l_value = getParameterByName('l');
var e_value = getParameterByName('e');
var ph_value = getParameterByName('ph');
var id_value = getParameterByName('id');
(function( $ ) {
    $( "#js-caller" ).on( "click", function( event ){
        const myUrlWithParams = new URL("https://website.com/new-url/");
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("f", f_value);
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("l", l_value);
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("e", e_value);
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("ph", ph_value);
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("id", id_value);

        console.log(myUrlWithParams.href);
        alert(myUrlWithParams);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
function getParameterByName(name, url = window.location.href) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
var f_value = getParameterByName('f');
var l_value = getParameterByName('l');
var e_value = getParameterByName('e');
var ph_value = getParameterByName('ph');
var id_value = getParameterByName('id');
(function( $ ) {
    $( "#js-caller" ).on( "click", function( event ){
        const myUrlWithParams = new URL("https://website.com/new-url/");
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("f", f_value);
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("l", l_value);
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("e", e_value);
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("ph", ph_value);
        myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("id", id_value);
        console.log(myUrlWithParams.href);
        alert(myUrlWithParams);//for testing the new url (and it works!)
        event.preventDefault();//to stop the Divi default event
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Why not simply slice the url string, starting at the index of the `?`  If you are going to take query string X, chunk it up, and reconstruct X exactly how it was, the chunking is unnecessary

Comment: Hi @Taplar and thank you for your message. You're totaly right but I realy don't know how to do it (1st day to try js...) so I take this js I found

Comment: `url.indexOf('?')` will get you the index of the `?` if it is there.  And then you can `url.slice(thatIndex)` to get the string, including the `?`

Comment: @ThomasSablik I'm suggesting this is an X/Y problem.  Rather than figuring out what is wrong with this logic that attempts to chunk up the url query string to later reconstruct it, I am saying that is unnecessary in this use case.  Just grab the query string.  Chunking is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi @ThomasSablik, thank you. Yes, this code works but impossible for me to put the new url in place of the old one in the href value of the button id="js-caller"...

Comment: @ThomasSablik : indeed for the cargo cult programming but I try to do my best and I spent all the day to find a solution before asking help. I try to learn and understand...

Comment: @ThomasSablik, my goal is to inject the new url in button href that contains the old one. The alert box shows that myUrlWithParams works fine but I don't know how to place it in the href. I tried "event.myUrlWithParams();" but it doesn't work

Comment: @Thomas : indeed, a button doesn't have a href. Here is my code :
<a id="js-caller" class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_0 et_pb_bg_layout_dark" href="https://website.com/currentURL/">Button Text</a>
So now I want to replace the currentUrl by the newUrl. I'm blocked at this point. As said, I tried to replace in the event.preventDefault(); by event.newUrl() but it doesn't work...

Comment: @ThomasSablik : the Taplar's answer seems to work. I adapted like this :
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
and
var BrandNewUrl = (newUrl + currentUrl.slice(indexOfQuestionMark));
and
alert(BrandNewUrl);
and it works even if my original goal is not yet achieved but I learn little bit more with that. I know my request isn't clear but I hope you understand much better my problem.
And sorry for my bad english spoken :-) Now I've to find a way to change the CurrentUrl that is in the href for the <a id="js-caller" (my button) by the BrandNewUrl ...

Comment: Thank you very much @ThomasSablik for your answer. I'm trying it  but without success for the moment.There is only a id for the <a but not for the "button" it is a Div with CSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var currentUrl = 'https://website.com/current-url/?f=John&l=Doe';
var newUrl = 'https://website.com/new-url/';
var indexOfQuestionMark = currentUrl.indexOf('?');

console.log(newUrl + currentUrl.slice(indexOfQuestionMark));
```

You don't need to chunk up the query string if you want to simply copy it to a different url.  Just slice it off and append it to the other url.

Comment: if you are using the current page URL to calculate it, it can be even simpler like:

`const newUrl = 'https://website.com/new-url + window.location.hash`

in this case you even keep the `#anchor` part assuming you have it for something.

Comment: @ThomasSablik it's definitely an answer, a simple one but it's an answer as it solves the OP problem of setting the params to a new URL.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I never said it is the query parameters. It's, as you said, everything after `#` which will inevitably include the query string.

I agree with the point about not setting the link on the button, but again OP question isn't clear. The thing about taking all query string parameters can be deducted by other comments from OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225735/discussion-between-renan-souza-and-thomas-sablik).

Comment: @Taplar, as the currentUrl may change regarding its parameters, I made this :
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
and
var BrandNewUrl = (newUrl + currentUrl.slice(indexOfQuestionMark));
and
alert(BrandNewUrl);
It works fine, thank you very much!
Now I've to find a way to change the original href for the <a id="js-caller" (my button)

Comment: `document.querySelector('#js-caller').href = brandNewUrl;` <= The point of the answer is that given a url string, no matter where you get it from, you can strip the query string off and append it to another string.  What you do with that new string at that point is only limited to what you choose to limit it to. @Thommen

Comment: @Taplar : It works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help Taplar, it has helped me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.search` returns the params, so say if the current URL you are on is https://example.com?utm_source=ap&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=intro&utm_id=eml

And you wanted a link to https://app.example.com in the page that copies over (includes) those query params, you can simply...

```js
const url = `https://app.example.com${window.location.search}`;
```

Which would return https://app.example.com?utm_source=ap&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=intro&utm_id=eml